# How can I execute php as an post on a MVC C# application?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, form-submit

I have a simple C# asp.net MVC5 project with some bootstrap and other fancy css plugins.

I have little experience with this so I may have missed some basic logic.

So I have this fancy php that will send a styled e-mail to our customers.

The way the view is set up is like this:

```
<form (...) method="post" action="sendemail.php">
```

As you can see, it really does not make sence to post to "sendemail.php" in a C# MVC application.

I do, however, want to use the logic set in sendemail.php to send this email. I am not able to map in the sendemail.php to a controller/view (because it only(?) accepts .cshtml).

Anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

This is the complete code in the form on the Contact.cshtml file:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Why not send the email from your MVC application? Why are you trying to run a PHP script from a .NET web app? If you don't want to rewrite the script to be a proper controller action, you will have to host the script as a PHP app inside IIS (or anywhere else) and then post to it as usual (in which case this is really nothing to do with MVC and the question is simply "how do I host a PHP script?". http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configure-a-php-website-on-iis

Comment: As I said, it is a lot of fancy logic to put together a mail with a bunch of templates etc. in that sendemail.php file. I really don't want to reimplement all that logic

Comment: Then just host the PHP script somewhere and set the form action to point to it as you already have. This article talks you through hosting PHP in IIS: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php

Comment: You can probably also host the script from the same IIS application as your MVC app by configuring the right handler mappings.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, because after all it is all about a `POST` request.

It does not matter what the post server side programming language is.

Simply post your request to the PHP script, then redirect it back to your MVC application.